# get list of the strings present in strings.xml file in Android

Tags: android

I want the list of strings present in the strings.xml file.

Does anyone knows how to get it??? One thing I found is it assigns the ids in sequential order inside R.java but how to get the starting id is not clear.

For Example I have 100 Strings in my strings.xml like below and I want to read in at a time not like giving getResources().getString(int id) for individual.

```
<string name="app_label">Calendar</string>
<string name="what_label">What</string>
<string name="where_label">Where</string>
<string name="when_label">When</string>
<string name="timezone_label">Time zone</string>
<string name="attendees_label">Guests</string>
<string name="today">Today</string>
<string name="tomorrow">Tomorrow</string>
```

Comment: you can get it by using getResources.getString("your_string_name");

Comment: I know that but I want list of all strings if I use this method I have to give ids of all strings say if 100 strings are there I have to write this 100 times

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820645/compare-names-of-every-resource-with-the-content-of-a-variable-of-sqlite-databas/13821330#13821330

Comment: @Luksprog Thanks Man !!!! Its working Fine .. Could please add this link as an answer so I can accept it and everyone can also refer the same :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to access all the Strings from the `strings.xml` file you could use reflection on the `R.string` class. An example can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820645/compare-names-of-every-resource-with-the-content-of-a-variable-of-sqlite-databas/13821330#13821330), you'll just need to replace drawables with strings.

Comment: It returns keys what to do for values?

Answer (score 15):

You can declare your strings in res\values\strings.xml file like this.

```
 <string-array name="vehiclescategory_array">

        <item>Cars</item>
        <item>Bikes</item>
        <item>RVs</item>
        <item>Trucks</item>
        <item>Other Vehicles</item>

 </string-array>
```

In your activity class, you can access them like the following.

```
String[] categories;

categories=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.vehiclescategory_array);
```

In the above list, whatever sequence you declare, the same way it is assigned to the array in your activity. Suppose Cars will be assigned to categories[0]. Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks fine :) but my problem is I have strings defined already as single elements in xml file and I have to read all of those strings

Comment: Added more explanation for your refrence Appu :)

Comment: You need ids from the strings? If so, have you tried with getIdentifier()? But I might have to say that if you don't use array, you need to mention every String name in your activity code to get the id of the respective string if I understood you correctly.

Comment: yes you are right I have to give pass each R.id to get name but  somehow if I can get first Id of the string i can increment that until I get null.


For Example if first string is R.id.hello than

String s = getResources.getString(R.id.hello+i);

Untill I get null, but problem is how to find which string got the first id

Comment: **R.id.hello+i** is not gonna work. you have to find some other alternative.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj I have tried it works fine but there is no way to find least allocated it in strings section of R.java so maybe I need a different approach

Comment: why dont you check from the **R.java** file.?

Comment: Any idea how to access it? I have also observed that sometimes it doesnt arranges the entry in sequential order though it gives id incrementally

Comment: @BrijeshMasrani: obviously by opening **R.java** file.! It arranges the entries in sequential order, unless you delete any of the entries.

Answer (score 10):

```
Field[] fields = R.string.class.getDeclaredFields(); // or Field[] fields = R.string.class.getFields();
String str = "";
for (int  i =0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(fields[i].getName(), "string", getPackageName());
    str += fields[i].getName() + " = ";
    if (resId != 0) {
        str += getResources().getString(resId);
    }
    str += "\n";
}
```

You will get all codes of strings with its values in "str" variable.

Answer (score 3):

You could declare an integer array with an entry for each string. I did this for an array of colors once, so I imagine it works for strings as well.

**res/values/arrays.xml**

```
<integer-array name="app_strings">
    <item>@string/app_label</item>
    <item>@string/what_label</item>
    <item>@string/where_label</item>
    <item>@string/when_label</item>
    <item>@string/timezone_label</item>
    <item>@string/attendees_label</item>
    <item>@string/today</item>
    <item>@string/tomorrow</item>
</integer-array>
```

Then in your code, you would loop over the array and use each value as the argument for getString().

```
int[] stringIds = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.app_strings);
String[] strings = new String[stringIds.length];
for (int i = 0; i < stringIds.length; i++) {
    strings[i] = getString(stringIds[i]);
}
```

The problem is you have to manually update your arrays.xml whenever you modify your string resources, so it's certainly not ideal.

Comment: tidiest answer so far

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] categories = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stars_array);
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(categories));
```

use this simple one