# How can I parse the strings.xml file in Android into an ArrayList<String>?

Tags: android, xml, string, arraylist

I would like to get all values that are stored in the strings.xml file and store them in an array list that holds just strings.
What would be the easiest way to achieve this??

Comment: some reflection on `R.string`

Comment: Why?  Why not store them as a string array?

Comment: what would be the purpose of this?

Comment: Why does it need you?

Comment: the purpose of this would be to compare them against another array list.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13821330/1276374

Comment: Just create one long string array then, its the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with this one-liner:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.strings)));//where R.array.strings is a reference to your resource
```